# Partial View Script in FlashMessanger

Tags: php, zend-framework2, flash-message

Is there a way to parse a partial view script as a flash message?

Iam using some big flash messages with html code blocks in it and the ability to read or format those messages is really bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's several ways to address the issue you're talking about and cptnk offered you one. However so much code within View-Files isn't often something you want. Luckily ZF2 offers a way to configure the same thing via configuration, too:

```
'view_helper_config' => array(
    'flashmessenger' => array(
        'message_open_format'      => '<ul><li>',
        'message_separator_string' => '</li><li>',
        'message_close_string'     => '</li></ul>'
    )
)
```

This has all been covered within [the official documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.helpers.flash-messenger.html) by me quite a time ago including an example of a Twitter Bootstrap 3 FlashMessenger layout. You may want to check this out for yourself.

And to give you a straight out answer to your initial question: **no it's not possible** to have a dedicated view-file to be used by the flashMessenger plugin. You'd have to write your own flashMessenger implementation for this.

Answer (score 2):

Did you take a look at the html layouting the view helper offers?

```
echo $this->flashMessenger()
  ->setMessageOpenFormat('<div%s><p>')
  ->setMessageSeparatorString('</p><p>')
  ->setMessageCloseString('</p></div>')
  ->render('success');
```

This example create's a div with the class `success` and nested "p's". When adding some more tag's to the `setMessageOpenFormat` make sure to close them with the `setMessageCloseString`.

Answer (score 1):

How about make partial and pass flashMessenger to it ?

```
<?php // partial.phtml ?>

flashMassenger: <pre><?php var_dump($this->flashMassenger) ?></pre>
```

You would then call it from your view script using the following:

```
<?php echo $this->partial('partial.phtml', array(
    'flashMassenger' => $this->flashMessenger())); ?>
```