# Diffrent settings in module.config.php for every module in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have got two modules: admin and application in first have:

```
'view_helper_config' => array(
        'flashmessenger' => array(
            'message_open_format'      => '<div%s><button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>',
            'message_separator_string' => '<br>',
            'message_close_string'     => '</div>'
        ),
    ),
```

in second have:

```
'view_helper_config' => array(
    'flashmessenger' => array(
        'message_open_format'      => '<ul%s><li>',
        'message_separator_string' => '<li></li>',
        'message_close_string'     => '</li></ul>'
    ),
),
```

and it's always merged. I would like to have on every module diffrent config. How can I do it?

Comment: Extend the flashmessenger and give him the same functionality with another alias. Or override the message_open_format, message_seperator_string, message_close_string within the module you need it to be diffrent. Check my answer in this question this may is what you actually need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399861/partial-view-script-in-flashmessanger/22400236#22400236

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that your `module.config.php` files act a bit like cascading style sheets in that the first one gets loaded and then the settings in the subsequent files either supplement or replace the settings that were loaded by the previous files.  The `module.config.php` files get loaded in the order that the modules are listed in `project\config\application.config`.  In other words, the statements that you have included in two different files are equivalent to listing them one after another in the same `module.config.php`.

There are several solutions to your question:

1. **Clone the helper** by extending it and giving it a different name, and use different versions in different modules. (If you do this you
   might even be able to set the default HTML strings in the aliases
   and avoid setting them in `module.config.php` altogether).
2. **Set the HTML strings in your views** rather than in `module.config.php`.  Look at the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.flash-messenger.html#html-layout) to learn how.
3. **Clone your `layout.phtml` and set the strings in there**.  The solution above requires that you set the HTML strings in each and
   every view that you create, but the documentation says you can set
   them in any `.phtml`.   [EdpModuleLayouts](https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts) allows you to have
   separate, module-specific layouts; and you can create a different
   layout for each module and set your chosen HTML strings in each
   layout.
4. **Toggle HTML strings on and off with CSS classes**.  I use EdpModuleLayouts so that the skin for my admin module is strikingly
   different from the other module(s), and so I already have alternate
   CSS files for different modules.  With these, it is possible to
   toggle HTML strings on and off.  For your application you could put
   a `class=”toggleFM”` in relevant tags and set the CSS settings to
   `display: hidden;` accordingly so that in one module certain
   elements are rendered and in another module other elements are
   rendered.  This is a convoluted solution, but it allows you to set
   the HTML strings in your `module.config.php` files if that’s what you
   want to do.

### EDIT

Also, take a look at your separator string.  You probably want `'</li><li>'` and not `'<li></li>'` because the separator closes a list item and opens another.